# How to update a record based on the primary key PUT method Express node.js

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, express

I am a bit confused on how to use the put statement in node js at the moment, currently I am using:

```
app.put("/cars/:id", (req, res)  => { //get record based on id (uuid) e.g. http://localhost:3000/cars/a5ad957c-7d1b-11eb-8a21-0653a157c10e
        connection.connect(function(err) {
            connection.query(`UPDATE main.cars SET manufacturer= '${req.params.manufacturer}', WHERE id = '${req.params.id}')`, function(err, result, fields) {
                if(err) res.send(err);
                if(result) res.send(result);
            });
                
            });
        });
```

But I receive the following error in postman:

{
"code": "ER_PARSE_ERROR",
"errno": 1064,
"sqlMessage": "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE id = 'a5ad957c-7d1b-11eb-8a21-0653a157c10e')' at line 1",
"sqlState": "42000",
"index": 0,
"sql": "UPDATE main.cars SET manufacturer= 'undefined', WHERE id = 'a5ad957c-7d1b-11eb-8a21-0653a157c10e')"

When I use the following query:

```
http://localhost:3000/cars/a5ad957c-7d1b-11eb-8a21-0653a157c10e?manufacturer=prius
```

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer here is that strings in SQL must be quoted with `'` characters.

… however while adding them is a simple fix, it would leave you vulnerable to [SQL injection attacks](https://bobby-tables.com/).

Look up how to use **parameterized queries** in whatever SQL library is giving you your `connection` object.